# Covering Panel with another

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub frmitem_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    pnldeposit.Visible = False
    pnlwithdraw.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdideposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdideposit.Click
    pnldeposit.Visible = True
    pnlwithdraw.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdiwithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdiwithdraw.Click
    pnlwithdraw.Visible = True
    pnldeposit.Visible = False
End Sub
```

//i am having problem with this form. i want to show the first panel which is successful, but the problem is showing the second panel. it is not working, im using buttons btw. help me. Thank you in advance :D

Comment: Have you tried using the `BringToFront` method?

Comment: i tried but it didn;t worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub cmdideposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdideposit.Click
    pnldeposit.Visible = True
    pnlwithdraw.Visible = False
    pnlreport.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmddcancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    pnldeposit.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdiwithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdiwithdraw.Click

    pnlwithdraw.Visible = True
    pnlreport.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdwclear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdwclear.Click
    pnlwithdraw.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdireport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdireport.Click
    pnlreport.Visible = True
End Sub
```

//thank you for sharing your idea! i found how it works. thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example using `BringToFront`. With both panels having the same Location and being the same Size.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private switchPanels As Boolean
  Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
    switchPanels = Not switchPanels
    If switchPanels Then
        Panel1.BringToFront()
    Else
        Panel2.BringToFront()
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your idea :D i found another way :D thanks!